Swift convert nested dictionary to protobuf
I am new to Protobuf.
Is possible to convert nested dictionary in swift of type [String: Any?] with swift protobuf?
How should I define it in a proto file?

Isn't it the other way around, you create a protobuf file and then you generate swift code from it? Also, try to avoid using Any in your swift code if possible
